# Passing Authorization Basic Headers Along in Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, http-headers, authorization

I am currently trying to get a reverse/forward proxy to pass along the authorization headers to the target server. How would I go abou this? I have already looked at the below sources, and one of the comments states that this only works for Proxy-Auth headers. However the proxy has no authenication backend. It looks like the below

User -> Proxy(No Auth Req) -> Backend(HTTP AUTH HERE)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213028/setting-up-mod-proxy-to-pass-http-authentication-to-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a mod rewrite thing

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The above rule needs to be applied at the proxy.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you post here how was the file in the end so I can have an idea what exactly you did to solve that? Thanks

Comment: @Adonist This just went on your proxy server. With `RewriteEngine on`. That is all. It's just one rule in your apache conf for that specific proxy site.